# Yup keeps running validators on the same property when .required() is false

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

I'm a bit confused about how `yup` is working.

I have the following schema to validate the register

```
export const registerValidationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    first_name: yup.string().trim().required(),
    last_name: yup.string().trim().required(),
    date_of_birth: yup.date().required().test('DOB', 'You must be at least 18 to register', value => {
        return value.setFullYear(value.getFullYear() + 18) < Date.now()
    }),
    email: yup.email().trim().required()
});
```

When the object to validate is the following

```
const data = {
    email: "john.doe@company.com"
}
```

The validation will crash because `value` is undefined and the function `value.setFullYear` will fail. But why? I assume that yup will stop this line on `.required()` part and go to the next property.

I know the issue can be fixed by adding `if(!value) return false;` inside `.test()` but what's the point of the required function?

From the yup documentation:

**string.required(message?: string | function): Schema**

The same as the mixed() schema required, except that empty strings are also considered 'missing' values.

**mixed.required(message?: string | function): Schema**

Mark the schema as required, which will not allow undefined or null as a value. Note that unless a schema is marked as nullable() a null value is treated as a type error, not a missing value. Mark a schema as mixed().nullable().required() treat null as missing.

So I read this as an `undefined`, `null` or `''` value should fail on the `.required()` rule.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `email: yup.email().trim().required()`
Try `email: yup.string().trim().email().required()`

found in [github documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup#getting-started)

```
const registerValidationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  first_name: yup.string().trim().required(),
  last_name: yup.string().trim().required(),
  date_of_birth: yup.date().required().test('DOB', 'You must be at least 18 to register', value => {
    return value.setFullYear(value.getFullYear() + 18) < Date.now()
  }),
  // email: yup.email().trim().required
  // modified
  email: yup.string().trim().email().required()
})

const data = {
  first_name: "john",
  last_name: "deo",
  date_of_birth: "12-jan-2000",
  email: " john.doe@gamil.com "
}

// validating schema
registerValidationSchema.isValid(data)
  .then(r => console.log(r))
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Comment: trim() is removing whitespaces in front or at the end of a string. For example '  john.doe@example.com ' will be transformed to 'john.doe@example.com'
Anyway, the question is not about whitespaces.

Comment: Sorry about previous answer, I have updated my answer Please can you check if these code works for your use-case.